# How to wrap json list to object with map

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I try to create api client in plain java without Spring or other frameworks uses Gson or Codehaus Jackson library. 
Thre are many types of Json responses. Like this:

```
{
  "any_name1": {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2
  },
  "any_name2": {
    "field1": 3,
    "field2": 4
  }
  ...
}
```

It has any name of objects and the same fields.
Or this:

```
{
    "field1":1,
    "field2":{
        "obj1":{
            "field1":1,
            "field2":2
        }
        ...
    }
 }
```

It should work with this call:

```
AnyTypeResponse response = apiClient.sendRequest(request, AnyTypeResponse.class);
```

I send type of response which I want to get from client.
With second json example it's clear. Object have two fields, one of them is list.
But first json example is list of objects. For example I don't need a list but I need one object with list (or map) inside. That means I need to wrap list of objects in one custom response object. How can I do that?
Now I use this method:

```
public <T> T execute(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    ...
    // create HttpUrlConnection and send request
    ...
    return objectMapper.readValue(response.toString(), clazz);
    // or return gson.fromJson(response.toString(), clazz);
}

public class ListTypeResponse {

    private List<AnyObj> objects;

    public ListTypeResponse(List<AnyObj> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public List<AnyObj> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
}
```

But it not works. Can you help me?

Comment: Unless `But it not works` is further clarifier (How does it not work?) your questions lack a MCVE ([mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Both types of JSON can be represented as `Map<String, Object>`, where the `Object` can also be a `Map<String, Object>`, and so on.

Using `Gson` you can create this map as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> o = gson.fromJson(jsonString, 
                                      new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

I used the debugger to demonstrate how `Gson` creates these nested maps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like what I need. 
But result is Map. How to create the one result object with this map inside of it?

Comment: @Virkom you could have an object with a `Map<String, Object>` field and create it like `new Result(map)`

Comment: Like your `ListTypeResponse ` but with a `Map` instead of a `List`